# How to add the "Functions tab" to Google's blockly

Tags: javascript, code-generation, blockly

According to the Demo that comes with blockly, we only have logic, loops, maths and text options when generation our code. here: https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/generator/index.html

How do I add the functions and variables tab since the documentation provide seems quite shallow. Documentation: https://developers.google.com/blockly/installation/code-generators

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "menu items" or "tabs" on the left of blockly demos make up the "Toolbox"
In order to add more items on the tool box, check https://developers.google.com/blockly/installation/toolbox

For example, in the case of adding the Functions and Variables to the Toolbox, add the xml code below to your index.html.

```
<category name="Variables" custom="VARIABLE"></category>
<category name="Functions" custom="PROCEDURE"></category>
```

A little inspection of index.html will tell you where the xml code is compiled and you'll insert your code appropriately.